# Increment and assign atomic

Tags: c#, .net

I want to increment a int variable and assign it to another int in a atomic operation.

I know about [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8) method. But as I understand it can only increment the passed variable atomicly, but not assign the result to a new variable.

So my approach is to lock on a object like this:

```
private static int globalCounter;
private static object LockObject;
private int localCounter;

/* ... */

lock (LockObject)
{
    globalCounter++;

    localCounter = globalCounter;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Well, get the return value : `localCounter = Interlocked.Increment(ref globalCounter);`

Comment: I don't think there is. Although your code inside the `lock()` can be simplified to `localCounter = ++globalCounter;`

Comment: @Cid This was my first thought, but is the assignment also within the atomic operation?